# HttpBrowserCapabilities not working while using Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using HttpBrowserCapabilities to check the users browser. But when using chrome to debug i'm getting in objBcp as "AppleMAC-Safari". While using IE it shows correctly as "IE".

```
     System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities objBcp= Request.Browser;
        if(objBcp.Browser=="Chrome")
{}
```

Is there other extension for Chrome?

Comment: Use ASP.NET 4 Browser Definitions http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41420

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using UserAgent for that purpose, for example:

```
if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("Chrome"))
{
    ...
}
```